# SAP UI Mail Compose For Image Uploader Showing Image Dimension. I need to remove this option from image Uploader

Tags: javascript, sap

We are using little bit older version of SAP UI. Back end is PHP. But now the issue is client don't need this image dimension option in file uploader.

I don't know how to change this option from uploader.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean SAPUI5?

Comment: Yes. But it's little older version

Comment: Sorry, I guess you're talking about something different. SAPUI5 is not a version 5, it's a Javascript library with "5" in its name. What is "SAP UI"? Do you have a link?